# Memory leak in drawing OpenGL framebuffer to UIImage

Tags: ios, memory-management, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am using OpenGL to do my drawing on screen and want to draw a portion of the screen to a UIImage. This is code I've cobbled together looking at examples, which works, but produces a memory leak every time it's called. I've tested this on device and the leak still persists and eventually causes a crash. The returned UIImage is saved to an instance variable and is later definitely set to nil again. What is causing the memory leak here?

```
- (UIImage *)renderToImageWithContentFrame:(CGRect)contentFrame
                               exportFrame:(CGRect)exportFrame
                                     scale:(float)scale {

    float screenWidth = contentFrame.size.width * scale;
    float screenHeight = contentFrame.size.height * scale;

    GLuint framebuffer;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

    GLuint renderTex;
    glGenTextures(1, &renderTex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex, 0);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    [self _renderImageGL];

    // grabbing image from FBO

    NSInteger dataLength = screenWidth * screenHeight * 4;
    GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);

    CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(screenWidth, screenHeight, 8, 32, screenWidth * 4, colorspace,
                                    kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,
                                    ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    float x = (exportFrame.origin.x - contentFrame.origin.x) * scale;
    float y = (exportFrame.origin.y - contentFrame.origin.y) * scale;
    float width = exportFrame.size.width * scale;
    float height = exportFrame.size.height * scale;
    CGImageRef cropped = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(iref, (CGRect){x, y, width, height});

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext((CGSize){width, height});
    CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, (CGRect){0, 0, width, height}, cropped);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    free(data);
    CFRelease(ref);
    CFRelease(colorspace);
    CGImageRelease(iref);
    CGImageRelease(cropped);

    return image;

}
```

Comment: Where does the Leaks instrument say the leak is? Also, where do you free `data`, and `renderTex`?

Comment: @user1118321 The memory leak was because I didn't free `renderTex`. Thanks for pointing it out. The leak did not show up in instruments. Is that true of all OpenGL leaks? Feel free to do an answer writeup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `renderTex` is not being freed (via a call to `glDeleteTextures(1, &renderTex);`). My guess is that Instruments may not know about OpenGL-allocated memory because that memory may reside on a graphics card and may be harder (or impossible) to track. (Though that's mainly a guess.)

Comment: Texture memory being opaque to instruments has been my experience, circa iOS5.